# Linking new views to tabs in an iOS app?

Tags: ios

So I'm very new to iOS and I'm trying to make an application with two tabs.  I want the first tab take me to an app I previously made (a simple iOS calculator) and the second should bring me to a navigation controller with 3 buttons. How do I reassign the tabs to bring me to these views? I'm trying to learn more about storyboard and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @prisonbreakx I would take your main view controller lets say Home, and go to Editor at the top, Embed In, then select TabBar. This should build in a tab bar with just one item, then you can build segues from your TabBarController to other views. 
 
 Here is a link to a very simple 3 page tab bar project I just threw together for you, its on GitHub at: https://github.com/dombryan94/exampleTabBarProj 
Just download the zip and rrun the xcode file right out of it and you can get an idea for what I mean. Feel free to just use this to build your project on.